# Using MATLAB to plot the input and the magnitude spectrum of the signal

Tags: matlab, fourier-transform, continuous-signals

I have an aperiodic signal $v_{out} = e^{-t} u(t)$ (real exponential signal) from discharging capacitor.

I was trying to plot using MATLAB 15 seconds of this signal in time domain? I am thinking how to plot because I donot know $u(t)$. But I am seeing many sources they involve the term $u(t)$ and the Fourier transform is independent of $u(t)$.

I found the Fourier transform  $V_{out}$ of $v_{out}$ to be $\frac{1}{1+j\omega}$ where $\omega = \frac{2\pi}{T}$.

$|V_{out}(j\omega)| = \frac{1}{1 + \omega^2} $

How do I plot the magnitude spectrum?(Is it the plot betwen $|V_{out}(j\omega)|$ and $\omega$?)

Comment: your equation is not fully formed without defining your symbols. t is most likely time but you need to define u. My guess would be that u is a constant, otherwise you would have a multivariable equation which does not have a single fourier transform. If u is constant you need to plot a time series using a constant and a time t for t=0-15 seconds, you can then fft that signal to get a spectrum.

Comment: In this kind of context, u(t) is often the [Heaviside step function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function). And yes, you got the right thing for what you'd have to plot for the magnitude spectrum.